# Filtering out records in SQL with a join

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am creating an app that makes guest lists for greek life events at universities.

- The two tables I am working with are 'student' table and 'participant' table.
- The fields in the student table are: student_id, student_name, university, and chapter.
- Students with chapter id's are considered members, and students without chapter id's are considered guests when making guest lists(participant table).
- The participant table fields are: participant_id, member(which is related to student_id), guest (which is also related to student_id), and event.
  When trying to add guests to the guest list for an event, I wrote the following sql query to filter out students from different universities and that aren't in chapters and weren't already on the list:

  ```
    $student = getColumn("SELECT guest FROM participant WHERE event =     '$event'");
    $university = getSqlValue("SELECT university FROM student WHERE student_id = '$member'");

      $f->setOption('filter', 
      "SELECT student_name
      FROM  `student` 
      LEFT JOIN participant ON student.student_id = participant.guest
      WHERE student.chapter =  ''
      AND student.university =  '$university'
      AND participant.guest != '$student'");
  ```

So, I know this isn't going to work, because I have a whole array for $student, but even if I try it with one student id, the query doesn't work. It returns empty.  If I remove the last AND particpant.guest!= $student, then the query returns all the students at the university that are not members of a chapter.

My question has two parts:

1. Why wouldn't that query work with one value for student?
2. Can someone think of a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: To address your first part:  The problem is likely because of your last `AND` clause.  For `OUTER JOIN`s, you should put all comparison logic in the `ON` clause, as this will logically transform your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.  Try moving the last `AND` clause up to your `ON` condition.

Comment: @ Siyual - that just returned all the student records from that university 3 times.  here's another thing I just thought of.  I have the event id saved in $event. I thought to change the last line to `AND participant.event != '$event' ` but that returned empty as well.  With the left join student id = participant.guest, is it not checking participant.event?